# I'm stuck with the method of the conclusion

Tags: logic

The question says:
Pointing to a man, a woman says," He is the father of the only grandson of my father in law"
• It's an mcq with the options a) Son ,b) Brother , c)Grandfather and d) None of these.

The answer written is none of these. I couldn't even get the hint of how they came up with this conclusion.
Could anyone please explain me the 
method and the actual answer of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

So her father in law is the father of her partner. This man has only one grandson, and we are looking at his father. Which means the man being pointed at is the son (or son-in-law) of the father-in-law. Since we are looking at the "in-laws" we know that brother and grandfather aren't possible, and because we are looking at the "middle" generation, grandfather isn't possible.

The actual possibilities are husband or brother-in-law. (Or the partner of a sister-in-law).

Comment: I can agree with this. But after reading the answer and once again reading the question, I think the man is husband of the woman is more probable. Anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: @yenashah You can't really comment on the probability. You have no extra information which can lead you this conclusion.

Comment: Sir , I guess I made some mistake in telling that.... I meant: As it is written, "He is the father" and also, grandson of my father in law means that "the grandson of my father in law" is actually the son of the woman. And since it is mentioned " He is the father " it means that actually, the man is the woman's husband. Correct me, please.

Comment: We don't know how many children the father-in-law has. All we know is that he has _one_ grandson, and we are looking at that boy's father. It _could_ be her son, but it could just as likely be her nephew. Without more information we can't say with certainty

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Her father in law has no biological relationship to her, which excludes a), b) and c) without more reflection.